# Draw an area having only a point and distances to the 4 borders

Tags: java, features, geotools, map-drawing

Using Geotools with Swing GUI.

Is it possible to somehow create a shape having only one coordinate (Lat,Lon) and four distances in meters to the borders?

[image]

Lets say we have only the "C" point and four distances given in meters ( the blue lines ).

Now I need to draw the red shape but it is not so simple:

1. I will need to move and rotate this shape in the future because it is actually a ship.
2. It must still a vector because it must respect its size ( distance from the point to borders ) at any scale.

The MarineTraffic has done this. The green shapes are what I need and the little dots inside them are the coordinates I have. The distances are given by AIS-NMEA data.

[image]

My main concern is how to rotate it in the future.

Sorry if my question have no code or effort prove. I have no idea from where to start. I'm VERY new to Geotools.

Comment: I'd start with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528805/439194) and work from that

Comment: An easier solution might be to use either an [WKT Mark](https://docs.geotools.org/maintenance/userguide/library/render/wkt.html) and map units or a [custom mark factory](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/renderer/style/MarkFactory.html) and handle everything in the render including rotation.

Comment: Thanks. Many things to play now... :-)

Comment: @IanTurton just to clarify: I must use this WKT inside a style to create aditional geometries to my point. These will be my ship in question. So I'll must pass to Geotools a Point and the SLD with the WKT having instructions to draw the ship.  Is this correct?

Comment: ... and before this I need to do some math to know the positions relative to the Point to create the Polygon I'll pass inside the WKT.

Comment: ... and every time I rotate the ship I need to rotate every point of the Polygon and do all over again to repaint the ship or I have other simplest method? (Affine Transform rotate by the centroid and the reference point is not the centroid )

Comment: Well... not completly true: https://geotools-gt2-users.narkive.com/u9vDzTf6/affine-transformation

Comment: You can just specify the rotation in the SLD file (as a feature attribute) and the renderer will handle it.

Comment: Really? Good to know!! I'll do my research and put the results here. Thanks.

Comment: Just to keep: https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/style.html